# Storing data with fgets into Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, fgets

I'm a student new to programming so I deeply apologies if my question could be seen as stupid and a bit confused. So my issue is that I have to create a program through which the user can insert a bunch of numbers (we use fgets) and at the end, he gets printed all the numbers he previously typed. Now, I actually have a guideline from my teacher but I can't figure out how to store the numbers, in an array, so that I can use them later. I will leave the code provided by the teacher (I am not asking for someone to make my assignment I'm only looking for someone to explain to me what the code actually means in order to use it myself)
In my opinion, there are some issues (but probably it is just me not knowing much):

- It looks a bit inefficient especially because I can't type a not allowed value (the only ones allowed are between 0 and 100) even though while the loop is running I actually can, but they just get ignored.
- If I insert for example 22 numbers I will get as a result of only 21 printed values because the first one gets lost in the process of checking if it is an allowed value

I am actually really confused but going back to my original question, I would like if possible to have a better understanding of how something like this `array[variable]` works or if it is even possible.

Thank you very much in advance.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MINNUM 18
#define MAXNUM 30
#define NNUM   (MAXNUM - MINNUM + 1)
#define NMAX    100

int main() {
    char s[80];
    int n;
    int nums[NMAX];
    int i, num;

    /* input */
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
    n = atoi(s);

    /* if n <= 0 print and error message and exit */
    if (n <= 0 || n > NMAX) {
        printf("[ERROR]\n");
        
        return 0;
    }

    /* read only the allowed numbers */
    i = 0;
    do {
        fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
        num = atoi(s);

    /* save the number and increment 'i' only if the value is between 18 and 30 */
        if (num >= MINNUM && num <= MAXNUM) {
            nums[i] = num;
            i++;
        }
    } while (i < n);

    /* print */
    printf("[NUMBERS]\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d\n", nums[i]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not inefficient. There are a few issues with the code, but the loop just continues until you entered all the required numbers. That seems the logical way to do it. The main issues are that it should give an error when you input a wrong number, and when you enter a valid number followed by a bunch of others stuff, it just ignores the other stuff.

The first one doesn't get lost. The first one is the number of values you can input. It gets assigned to the variable `n`. The loop runs until you've entered that many numbers (`while(i < n)`)

An array is really just a sequence of values of the same type. You use the element access operator (`[]`) to get an individual element. In your example of `array[variable]`, `variable` is the index in `array`. How this works is pretty simple. `array` refers to a memory address, and an element can be accessed at a specified offset at that address; the offset being at index multiplied by the size of an element.